# cannot create new action

Tags: magento2, action

I want to create new action (like 'webrequest/index/search') on existed module. I created following https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/
But when I run http:///webrequest/index/search, the program go to default page (http://)
Please give me solution

Edited: I add my code

**Controller/Index/Search.php**

```
<?php
namespace Paymentpf\webrequest\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Search extends Action
{

        /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;
  /**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @param Context                                       $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory    $resultPageFactory
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|void
 */
public function execute()
{
     $cusSession = $this->_customerSession->getId();

         /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
         $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();   
         $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(
             __('新規請求登録')// UIUX 20200730
         );
         return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

webrequest_index_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Paymentpf\Webrequest\Block\Webrequest" name="webrequest_index_search" template="Paymentpf_Webrequest::webrequest_search.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

webrequest_search.phtml

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Share the complete code here

Comment: @ManashviBirla I updated my code in the topic

Comment: please share routes.xml code also

Comment: Check if it is a typo error in your namespace declaration webrequest or Webrequest?